# Label placing in ggplot2 using geom_text function in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, label, geom-text

I'm designing some graphs within a function with ggPlot2 geom_text.
It is a sequence of five graphs and, in each one, I want to place my label (my text) in the top right position.
The problem is that I will constantly change my N and Y values (according to and input interval). X and Y coordinates will change, and even be out of scale.
So how do I make the label placement fixed, let's say in the top right, in my graph?

Here's my code

```
parte.mac <- subset(dados, subset = (dados$Especie == 'C.macelaria' & dados$Temp >= minima & dados$Temp <= maxima))
  mac <- qplot(Temp, Tempo, data = parte.mac, color = Especie, main = 'C.macelaria', geom = c("point", "line"), add = T) +
    stat_smooth(method = 'lm', level = 0.99, alpha = 0.5, aes(group=1), color = 'blue') +
    geom_text(x = maxima, y = mean(range(dados$Tempo)), label = mac.sm, parse = TRUE)
```

Please, help

Comment: Could you provide a reproducible / minimum data?

Comment: typically this works, `p+ annotate("text", y=Inf, x=Inf, label="here")`, you may need to adjust `vjust/hjust`

Comment: hi baptiste and jazzurro, my temp data ranges from 10 - 50 and my tempo data ranges form 240 - 180

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Echoing the comment by @jazzuro, could you provide us with (your) reproducible data by running (don't send anything confidential!)

```
dput(parte.mac)
```

and pasting that with your question.

In the absence of your exact data, I'll echo @baptiste with a simple example using the "faithful" data file of the Old Faithful geyser eruptions:

```
data(faithful)
head(faithful)
p <- qplot(x=eruptions, y=waiting, data=faithful)
```

and then here is one example of an annotation:

```
p + annotate("text", x=3, y=40, label="Group 1") + annotate("text", x=4.5, y=60, label="Group 2")
```

Below is a second example, using arguments such as "min" and "max" for placement of the annotations:

```
p + annotate("text", x=min(faithful$eruptions), y=min(faithful$waiting), label="Group 1") + annotate("text", x=max(faithful$eruptions), y=max(faithful$waiting), label="Group 2")
```

If this doesn't help, remember to dput your data and paste into your question.

Comment: Thanks, Woodstock, it was the annotate function I was looking for! I got that going now, thaks a lot! :D